# Expression Engine Calendar using date field

Tags: calendar, expressionengine

I'm building a site using the exp:channel:calendar tag and would like to use a date field to add entries to the calendar rather then the publish date for the entry. I can't find any talk of this anywhere, is it possible? How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

- Just move the Entry Date filed into your custom publish layout in place of your custom date field.
- Use the [EEvent Helper add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/eevent-helper), which allows you to clone the value of a custom date field to the Entry Date when publishing or updating an entry.

Comment: How do you mean just move the Entry Date? I'm where in the template I'm meant to do this. I can't find any mention of appropriate tags to do this in the documentation, though I think I might still be missing something here.

Comment: In the control panel, you can drag the fields around, and between tabs. See http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/content/publish_page_layouts.html. But the add-on I linked to will, I think, solve your problem.  You can set the date for your event via a custom date field, ignoring the entry date entirely, but still have the channel:calendar tag use the correct date because the add-on copies the value of the custom date field to your entry date for you.

Comment: I have no idea how that feature of EE had completely escaped me, that's fantastic! Definitely going to come in extremely handy, can't believe I've not used it before.

Shall be using the plugin to address my problem this time round as it looks like it'll fit in nicely with the way I've been working.

Thanks again!